# Configuring clover exclude file patterns

Tags: java, ant, clover

Greetings,

I have clover 3.0 setup using ant, with the following file exclusions:

```
<clover-setup initString="${clover.initstring}" flushpolicy="threaded" flushinterval="30000">
    <methodContext name="tostring" regexp="(.* )?public String toString\(.*\).*" />
    <files>
        <exclude name="**/*Test.java" />
        <exclude name="**/entity/fields/*.java" />
    </files>
</clover-setup>
```

The *Test files are excluded correctly, as is the toString() calls, the files under the entity/fields package are not. Does the `<files>` ant type work with two excludes items? Can you have a partial package definition on your exclude name? I used `**/.....` format as the doc says something cryptic like

*An Ant patternset, relative to the top level package (e.g. com/cenqua/clovertest), element which controls which files are included or excluded from Clover instrumentation. Use this when you wish to exclude files based on packages.*

From this I read it starts at clovertest in the sample, although i'm not sure how it knows what the `top level package is`? Is that the first package with files?

As an example my java classes that i want to exclude are like

```
package com.acme.missileinabox.common.entity.fields;

public class ActivityFields {
   ....
}
```

Any idea what i'm foobaring? I posted the question [here](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=53418&tstart=0) with no response.

Comment: See also [Directory-based Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify a [`<fileset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html), possibly containing one or more [`<patternset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html)'s, as discussed under the [`<fileset>`](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup#clover-setup-Fileset) topic in [`<clover-setup>`](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup).

Addendum: If you change `<files>` to [`<fileset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html), you can use the latter's implicit [`<patternset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html) unchanged:

```
<fileset>
    <exclude name="**/*Test.java" />
    <exclude name="**/entity/fields/*.java" />
</fileset>
```

Alternatively, use `<files>` and nest an explicit [`<patternset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html):

```
<files>
    <patternset>
        <exclude name="**/*Test.java" />
        <exclude name="**/entity/fields/*.java" />
    </patternset>
</files>
```

Comment: See also [Why does Clover instrument classes I have excluded](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=79986960)?

Comment: hmm maybe this, `Excluded files are still registered in the Clover database:` -- checking

Comment: [Using Coverage Contexts](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+Coverage+Contexts) mentions, "At report time, you can specify which contexts you would like to exclude in the coverage report." Is that an alternative?

Comment: using the patternset in files, i saw no difference... I tried to copy the filter to report generation time.. no love for me.

Comment: Tabs in the source? Try `regexp="(.* )?public[ \t]String[ \t]toString\(.*\).*"`.

Comment: well that might be true somewhere, but, toString `IS` getting removed from the reports.

Comment: That makes sense. Looking at [`<clover-setup>`](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup), I don't see an example in which `<methodContext/>` contains a nested `<fileset/>`. Perhaps the <fileset/> should be a level up, and the `*Test` files are being excluded for an unrelated reason.

Comment: sorry, poor SO formatting made it look like fileset was a nested element of `<methodContext>`, notice that methodContext is an empty tag. i fixed it